# How the closure remove the memory for view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know about memory management in the closure.

for instance, we have a view controller that has a closure to finish. When I Check the reference count to the view controller it's showing the reference count 1.

When the memory will clear/remove for the dismissed view controller?

Here is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonToHide: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func showSecondViewController()  {
        guard let second  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") else { return  }
        present(second, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}



class SecondViewControler: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl:  UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(self) is being deinitialized") // still self object is there
        print(_getRetainCount(self)) // returning 1
    }

    @IBAction func dismissController()  {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() +  .seconds(6)) {
            self.lbl.text = "HHi"
            print("self reference : ",self.lbl.description)
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("viewDidDisappear", self.lbl.description)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please refer to the following and heading Strong Reference Cycles for Closures you will have great idea how it works.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: I think the reference count is going to be 1 unless the `deinit` method is done. So check the reference count after the dismiss totally is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html) instance is not deallocated right away  until after its deinitializer is called its still have reference count 1 for some time

> Deinitializers are called automatically, just before instance
>   deallocation takes place. You are not allowed to call a deinitializer
>   yourself. Superclass deinitializers are inherited by their subclasses,
>   and the superclass deinitializer is called automatically at the end of
>   a subclass deinitializer implementation. Superclass deinitializers are
>   always called, even if a subclass does not provide its own
>   deinitializer.
>
> Because an instance is not deallocated until after its deinitializer
>   is called, a deinitializer can access all properties of the instance
>   it is called on and can modify its behavior based on those properties
>   (such as looking up the name of a file that needs to be closed).